# Jack and Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, jack

Attempting to write some small midi programs with [rtmidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) on my Raspberry PI (Debian Wheezy). But, when I compile it, `g++` cannot find `jack/jack.h`.

However, when I run `sudo apt-get install jackd` it says I have everything up to date. I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/include/jack/jack.h` is provided by `libjack-dev` (jackd1) or `libjack-jackd2-dev` (jackd2) package.  You need to install either of them.

[Debian has the service](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages.en.html) where you can search for packages which contain specific files.  [Here's the result for `jack/jack.h`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=jack%2Fjack.h&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any).